# Parsing a complex, inter-related JSON model for storage inside of a Realm datastore

Tags: json, swift, api, parsing, realm

I am calling an external API to provide data for my application. The returned data is in a bit of a non-traditional format and some of the data is very inter-related. I am having trouble coming up with a good architecture for handling this data and storing it inside of Realm. Here is a sample of the data. *(Note: I have replaced real values with placeholders so the data is not necessarily semantically sound)*

```
[
   {
      "id":1,
      "name":"Matthew",
      "initial_locations":[
         "Location A"
      ],
      "new_locations":[
         "Location B",
         "Location C"
      ],
      "family":{
         "member":[
            [
               {
                  "id":1,
                  "name":"Matthew",
               }
            ],
            [
               {
                  "id":2,
                  "name":"Mark"
               }
            ],
            [
               {
                  "id":3,
                  "name":"Luke",
               }
            ]
         ],
         "relationship":[
            [
               {
                  "relation":"cousin",
                  "depth":1
               }
            ],
            [
               {
                  "relation":"cousin",
                  "depth":2
               }
            ]
         ]
      }
   },

   {
      "id":2,
      "name":"Mark",
      "initial_locations":[
         "Location B"
      ],
      "new_locations":[
         "Location A",
         "Location C"
      ],
      "family":{
         "member":[
            [
               {
                  "id":1,
                  "name":"Matthew",
               }
            ],
            [
               {
                  "id":2,
                  "name":"Mark"
               }
            ],
            [
               {
                  "id":3,
                  "name":"Luke",
               }
            ]
         ],
         "relationship":[
            [
               {
                  "relation":"cousin",
                  "depth":1
               }
            ],
            [
               {
                  "relation":"cousin",
                  "depth":2
               }
            ]
         ]
      }
   },

   {
      "id":3,
      "name":"Luke",
      "initial_locations":[
         "Location C"
      ],
      "new_locations":[
         "Location A",
         "Location B"
      ],
      "family":{
         "member":[
            [
               {
                  "id":1,
                  "name":"Matthew",
               }
            ],
            [
               {
                  "id":2,
                  "name":"Mark"
               }
            ],
            [
               {
                  "id":3,
                  "name":"Luke",
               }
            ]
         ],
         "relationship":[
            [
               {
                  "relation":"cousin",
                  "depth":1
               }
            ],
            [
               {
                  "relation":"cousin",
                  "depth":2
               }
            ]
         ]
      }
   }
]
```

This response is from a `getAll` and therefore returns an array of objects of the same type, let's call them `FamilyMember`.

As you can see, each`FamilyMember` two lists of locations: `initial_locations` and `new_locations`. Each `Location` may or may not be unique to that `FamilyMember` -- some `Location` are often shared between multiple `FamilyMember` and may be repeated dozens of times. This is the first piece of inter-related data.

Secondly, each `FamilyMember` contains a `Family` object representing the some amount of the family tree. The `Family` object is where the schema becomes very strange and non-standard, but I have no control over the scheme and have to work with what I am given. The `member` array contains a reduced form of a `FamilyMember`, a `FamilyMemberSummary`. The `relationship` array describes the type of relationship as well as how far removed (e.g. 2nd cousin). The `member` and `relationship` arrays are parallel -- `relationship[0]` describes the relationship between `FamilyMember` and the `FamilyMemberSummary` found at `member[0]` and so forth. This is the second, more intricate piece of inter-related data.

Given the schema, I want to design an architecture for parsing this data and storing it inside of a Realm. I have the Realm models designed without any issue, but I am having trouble figuring out how to handle these interconnected data points, avoiding duplicate objects, and preserving relationships.

For example, when I process `Matthew`, I gain knowledge about `Matthew` family members. However, `Mark` has not been processed yet because it's the second object in the root array; therefore, I have no `FamilyMember` object to place into `Matthew.familyMembers` to be related and stored in the Realm. It could be possible to create a stub `FamilyMember` with the small amount of information that is known about `Mark` but I'm not a huge fan of this approach.

Another complication with this interconnected data: for each `FamilyMember`, I will need to query the Realm for the any `FamilyMember` that are contained in `members` for the current `FamilyMember` in order to relate the objects (i.e. `currentFamilyMember.familyMembers.Add(fetchedFamilyMember)`). This adds a significant burden. For each new `FamilyMember`, I have to do a non-trivial amount of fetches just to properly set up the relationships.

This is also true for `Location`. When processing the `initial_locations` and `new_locations`, I have to query the Realm to see if any of the `Location` already exist. If so, I have to add those `Location` to the respect `List<Location>` on `FamilyMember` to create the appropriate relationship and to avoid duplicates.

As you can see, there is significant logic behind creating a `FamilyMember`. I am having a very hard time thinking about the best way to structure this parse-and-save code. At this point, it feels like I need an entire helper class just to parse and save a `FamilyMember`. I was hoping that someone here might give me a little insight or suggest some interesting idea that I hadn't considered yet.

I'm confident that I could find a solution on my own, but I am looking to find the most clean, efficient, and isolated solution as possible.

Quick Note: I am using RealmSwift. Also, I am only concerned with the JSON insofar as how the schema would best translate to Realm. I have taken care of all the fetching and serialization already.

Edit:

This is the Realm model that I currently have written out.

```
class FamilyMember: Object {

    @objc dynamic var id = 0
    @objc dynamic var name = ""
    let initialLocations = List<Location>()
    let newLocations = List<Location>()
    let members = List<Relationship>()

}

class Location: Object {
    @objc dynamic var name = ""
}

class Relationship: Object {
    @objc dynamic var to: FamilyMember?
    @objc dynamic var type = ""
    @objc dynamic var depth = 0
}
```

Comment: What do your Realm models look like?

Comment: @CliftonLabrum I hadn't necessarily finalized it yet but I have updated the original question with the current iteration.